# Restrict attribute routes to specific HTTP verbs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

With the AttributeRouting library I can restrict a route to a specific verb:

```
[Route("customers", HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

In MVC 5 AttributeRouting is built in, but there is no overload taking HttpVerbs. How do I restrict a route to POST in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `[HttpGet()]`, `[HttpPost()]`, `[HttpPut()]` to restrict the method to one or more supported Http method,

Comment: Is this restriction also added in the route itself? I am using this information when generating a sitemap.

Comment: all attributes are related to method not a route. So you can cross query to find httpmethod support.